# Alphabetizing strings and reversed strings?

Tags: java, string, sorting

For this program, I need to have the user input strings, which will then be put into an array along with their reversed counterparts. The entire array would then be alphabetized. So it should work like this:

- Input: strawberry banana, apple, grapes
- Output: apple, ananab, banana, elppa, grapes, separg, strawberry, yrrebwarts

I have the code for this, and it works to some degree. However, it only alphabetizes the reversed and the normal but separately. So it ends up looking like this:

- Output: ananab, elppa, separg, yrrebwarts, apple, banana, grapes, strawberry

As you can see it *is* alphabetizing the words to some degree, but not how it should be. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WordGame {

  public static void main(String[] args) { 
    String reverseInput = " "; //creates an empty string where the reverse will be stored before       putting it into the array
    String[] wordArray = new String[1000]; //creates an array that allows for 500 words, and 500     reverses of said words
    int s = 0;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter the words you would like to reverse. To finish entering words enter a blank line:");
    String userInput = sc.nextLine(); //allows for user to input words

    int length = userInput.length();
    int i = 0;

    while (!userInput.equals("")){ //runs until the user enters a blank line
      reverseInput = " ";
      for(i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        reverseInput += userInput.charAt(i); 
      wordArray[s] = userInput; //reverses user inputted strings by taking the last letter and putting it in front, repeating until the whole word is reversed
      wordArray[s + 1] = reverseInput; 
      s += 2;

      userInput = sc.nextLine();
      length = userInput.length();
    }

    for(int j = 0; j < s-1; j++){ //beginning of alphabetical sorting
      for(int k = 0; k < s-1-j; k++){
        int l = 0;
        while((int)wordArray[k].charAt(l) == (int)wordArray[k+1].charAt(l))
          l++;
        if ((int)wordArray[k].charAt(l) > (int)wordArray[k+1].charAt(l)){
          String holder = wordArray[k];
          wordArray[k] = wordArray[k+1];
          wordArray[k+1] = holder;
        }
      }

    }

        for(i = 0; i < wordArray.length; i++){
          if (wordArray[i]!= null){
            System.out.print(wordArray[i] + " "); //prints out contents of array
        }
        }
      }
    }
```

I am not sure what the issue is. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are there any constraints on what you can use? i.e. no Lists or you aren't allowed to use built-in sorting functions?

Comment: @vandale We cannot use built in sorting functions or Lists. Everything I have used here is pretty much the extent of what we can use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see you put an extra blank in front of your "reverseInput" with `reverseInput = " ";`
Because your reverse string won't start with a char you think (it starts with a blank) the result is not what you really want. Try to delete the blank and retry you code.

Comment: Tried this, unfortunately nothing changed.

Comment: and just an advice from me: Try to use brackets even if your for-statement use one line. Because `wordArray[s] = userInput;` is indented one can think it's part of your for-statement which it isn't. 
Further more 'creates an empty string where the reverse will be stored before' is wrong. You crate a string that is right, but you don't modify THIS string with "+=". Java creates with every =+ execution a NEW string with the concatenation and stores it in reverseInput.

Comment: it should work. You need to change the line after your while block begins. There you wrote `reverseInput = " ";`. Change this to `reverseInput = "";` and your code should work

Comment: I thought you meant the first reverseInput, but now I got it. You're a lifesaver! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are definitely easier ways to do this, depending on if you want to use Java's built in classes for this kind of thing.  I just wrote this up, it accomplishes the sort with reversed Strings that you want.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Solution {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
        values.add("strawberry");
        values.add("banana");
        values.add("apple");
        values.add("grapes");
        Solution s = new Solution();
        values = s.sortList(values);
        int itemCt = 1;
        for (String item : values) {
            System.out.println(itemCt + ": " + item);
            itemCt++;
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<String> sortList(List<String> strings) {
        ArrayList<String> combinedList = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (String str : strings) {
            combinedList.add(str);
            combinedList.add(new StringBuilder(str).reverse().toString());
        }
        Collections.sort(combinedList);
        return combinedList;
    }

}
```